# Unable to use field values inside fieldset at form level

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I am using two form in app.component.html file and I have below code, i am trying to use #mod.value and token.value in onSend() function as additonal parameter, but its not getting identified as reference content to the field like its identifying content.value (#content refers to a input field from first form)

Need help with cause of not identifying #mod and #token.

Note: some of the field used are custom field library

```html
<form [formGroup]="myForm" (ngSubmit)="onSend(content.value)" #f="ngForm">
    <div class="col">
      <div class="row justify-content-md-center">
        <button
          class="col-md-2"
          id="AddModel"
          text="Add Model"
          type="button"
          (click)="addModel()"
        >
        </button>

        <button
          class="col-md-2"
          id="sendAIBtn"
          text="Send to AI"
          type="submit"
        >
        </button>
      </div>

      <div formArrayName="models">
        <div
          *ngFor="let model of myForm.get('models')['controls']; let i = index"
        >
          <fieldset>
            <legend>
              <h4>
                Model {{ i + 1 }}:
                <button
                  style="margin-left: 35px"
                  type="button"
                  class="btn btn-danger"
                  (click)="deleteModel(i)"
                >
                  <span
                    class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"
                    aria-hidden="true"
                  ></span>
                  Remove Model
                </button>
              </h4>
            </legend>

            <div
              [formGroupName]="i"
            >
              <div class="form-group">
                <select
                  #mod
                  class="col-md-10"
                  label="Model"
                  value="text-davinci-001"
                  options='[{"name": "001", "value": "001"},{"name": "002", "value":"002"}]'
                  datamissing="Please check one option."
                  required
                >
                </select>

                <input-field
                  class="col-md-10"
                  #token
                  label="Max Tokens"
                  placeholder="500"
                  readonly
                >
                </input-field>

                <input-field
                  class="col-md-10"
                  label="Response:"
                  placeholder="Response Message"
                  value="{{ sendResponse }}"
                  rows="3"
                  readonly
                >
                </input-field>
              </div>
            </div>
          </fieldset>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
```

app.component.ts

```js
import { Component} from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { FormArray, FormBuilder, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent {

  data = {
    models: [
      {
        model: "",
        maxtoken: "",
        response: ""
      }
    ]
  }

  myForm: FormGroup

  constructor(
    private httpClient: HttpClient,
    private fb: FormBuilder
  ) {
      this.myForm = this.fb.group({
      models: this.fb.array([])
    })
    this.setModels();
  }
  

  private submitURL = "https://api";
  private sendURL = "https://api"
  message: string = '';
  maxTok: string = '';
  submitResponse: string  = '';
  sendResponse: string  = '';

  addModel() {
    debugger
    let control = <FormArray>this.myForm.controls.models;
    control.push(
      this.fb.group({
        model: [''],
        maxtoken: [''],
        response: ['']
      })
    )
  }

  deleteModel(index) {
    debugger
    let control = <FormArray>this.myForm.controls.models;
    control.removeAt(index)
  }

  setModels() {
    let control = <FormArray>this.myForm.controls.models;
    this.data.models.forEach(x => {
      control.push(this.fb.group({ 
        model: x.model, 
        maxtoken: x.maxtoken,
        response: x.response
      }))
    })
  }

  onSubmit(content: string): void {
    this.submitResponse = '';
    let auth_token = "some token";
    
    const headers = new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Authorization': `${auth_token}`
    });
  
    debugger;
    // Process checkout data here
    var data = {
      message: content
    }

    const requestOptions = { headers: headers };
  
    this.httpClient.post(this.submitURL, data, requestOptions).subscribe(res => {
        let response = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(res, null, 2));
        console.log(response)
        this.submitResponse = response.message
        if(this.submitResponse === "Message vetting is done. No PII or sensitive information is found.") {
        }
    });
  }

  onSend(content: string): void {
    this.sendResponse = '';
    let auth_token = "";
    
    const headers = new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Authorization': `${auth_token}`
    });
  
    var data = {
      message: content
    }

    const requestOptions = { headers: headers };
  
    this.httpClient.post(this.sendURL, data, requestOptions).subscribe(res => {
        let response = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(res, null, 2));
        this.sendResponse = response.message
    }) ;
  }
}
```

Comment: The problem is probably because of how template variables work in Angular. Since both are "created" inside an ngFor directive, they are only visible within that scope. You could access these elements from your ts file by using an approach like ViewChildren. Check this link for more details on template variables: https://angular.io/guide/template-reference-variables#template-variable-scope

Comment: Please share the typescript code.

Comment: You're using [Reactive Forms](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms), why nor use formControlName? and get the value as,e.g this.myForm.get('models.'+index+'name_of_control')?

Comment: Added app.component.ts file

Comment: Thanks much Eliseo. As i was using reactive forms, i must have used it after adding it started to work.

Answer (score 0):

In in onSend function:

```
onSend(content: string, event: any) {
   const modelsData = this.myForm.get('models').value.map((model) => {
  return {
    mod: model.mod,
    token: model.token,
  };
});

}
```

It would be great if you can share your typescript code.

Comment: It doesn't recognize mod and token value while passing to onSend() function. could be because of reason provided above.

Comment: added typescript function to my question

Comment: Please try this.

Comment: Thanks Kazi .. I tried this and I am getting null value only as the models array helps to add empty fieldset fields on AddModel() request and value is selected from these elements later, which is captured as #mod #token -- these values are what i am not sure how to fetch.

Comment: I got it, I had to add "ngDefaultControl" and formControlName for each field and data started to bind.

Comment: Thant's awesome @NoException. Congratulations!!! Best wishes.